# Difference between centre of mass of ring and solid sphere

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Centre of mass of ring and centre of mass of solid sphere is at the geometric centre but how the mass of ring will be less than the mass of the solid sphere? 
And
centre of mass depends upon mass, so I think they both will have different COM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well consider the definition of position of center of mass of the system given below:-$$\vec{r}_{com}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n m_{i}\vec{r}_{i}}{\sum_{i=1}^n m_{i}}$$
These kind of definitions are similar to the definitions in statistics related to the weighted average mean of something.

Here,the shapes are symmetric about their geometric centres.The definition of centre of mass suggests us that the position of centre of mass must be at its geometric centre.

Comment: No just I am saying that the mass of the circular plate (sorry not sphere ) is greater than mass of the ring of same diameter..Will there COG will differ? As the COG depend on mass.

Comment: First of all centre of gravity and centre of mass are different concepts.Well,I have quoted in my answer that position of centre of mass depends on weighted mean of positions of individual particles not the mass of the system considered.

Answer (score 0):

The centre of mass of a given geometric configuration depends on the mass **distribution** and not on the mass as such.

The centre of mass of a ring with uniform mass (this condition can be relaxed to restrict radially opposite mass elements to have the same mass) distribution lies at its geometric centre while a sphere with uniform mass distribution (can be relaxed to be radially symmetric) distribution has its centre of mass at its geometric centre.

Comment: No just I am saying that the mass of the circular plate (sorry not sphere ) is greater than mass of the ring of same diameter..Will there COG will differ? As the COG depend on mass.

Comment: No since as I have pointed out in my answer above, they depend on the mass distribution and not the mass as such. This is like asking if a heavier object would have a different centre of mass than a lighter (identical) one (the mass **distributions** being identical).